# User has overriden a file on SharePoint, no versioning, possible to restore the file?

Tags: sharepoint, backup

So the user seems to have overriden a file on a sharepoint list with no versioning. I don't know what SharePoint version it is, but it's definitely on prem (not online). A back-up was made yesterday, prior to the user overriding the file.

Is it possible to restore the file & restore everything back to normal from user admin/back-up? If yes, how?

Comment: Why the SQL tag?

Comment: What type of backup is this ? SQL ?

Comment: presumably yes.

Answer (score 0):

As the first step enable versioning to the current library.

If there is a SQL backup create a separate site or web application and over write the database of the newly created web application with the existing backup.
The you can access the site using the newly created webapp , download the file and upload it to the original site.
Do the restoring of the database in a test environment as its not recommended to create so many web applications (More than 6).

References
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot soon :)